# Uniform- or direct-initialization when initializing?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

Let's say I have a template that stores an object of type `T`. I want to pass constructor arguments in order to initialize the data member. Should I use uniform-initialization or direct-initialization with non-curly braces?:

```c++
template<typename T>
struct X
{
    template<typename... Args>
    X(Args&&... args)
             : t(std::forward<Args>(args)...) // ?
    /* or */ : t{std::forward<Args>(args)...} // ?
private:
    T t;
};
```

If the object I want to store is a `std::vector` and I choose the curly-brace style (uniform-initialization) then the arguments I pass will be forwarded to the `vector::vector(std::initializer_list<T>)` constructor, which may or may not be what I want.

On the other hand, if I use the non-curly brace style I loose the ability to add elements to the vector through its `std::initializer_list` constructor.

What form of initialization should I use when I don't know the object I am storing and the arguments that will be passed in?

Comment: also consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340801/uniform-initialization-fails-to-copy-when-object-has-no-data-members)

Comment: What about overloading that constructor to take an `initializer_list` ?

Comment: You say "the vector::vector(std::initializer_list<T>) constructor, which may or may not be what I want." - why would it not be?

Comment: When I try out this with g++ 4.9.1 it fails to deduce `Args` with a directly specified initializer list, but works regardless of kind () or {} when I pass a known `std::initializer_list<U>`, for type `T` as `std::vector<U>`.

Comment: If you really have no other choice, parens are more general than braces - you can still access the initalizer-list constructor with parens if you pass in a `std::initializer_list` object explicitly; if you use braces there's no real way to work around it short of constructing the object yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be clear the ambiguity arises for types having multiple constructors, including one taking an `std::initializer_list`, and another one whose parameters (when initialized with braces) may be interpreted as an `std::initializer_list` by the compiler. That is the case, for instance, with `std::vector<int>` :

```
template<typename T>
struct X1
{
    template<typename... Args>
    X1(Args&&... args)
             : t(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    T t;
};

template<typename T>
struct X2
{
    template<typename... Args>
    X2(Args&&... args)
     : t{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}

    T t;
};

int main() {
    auto x1 = X1<std::vector<int>> { 42, 2 };
    auto x2 = X2<std::vector<int>> { 42, 2 };
    
    std::cout << "size of X1.t : " << x1.t.size()
              << "\nsize of X2.t : " << x2.t.size();
}
```

(Note that the only difference is braces in `X2` members initializer list instead of parenthesis in `X1` members initializer list)

> **Output** :
>
> size of X1.t : 42
>
> size of X2.t : 2

**[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65c7f5c8621be26f)**

---

Standard Library authors faced this real problem when writing utility templates such as `std::make_unique`, `std::make_shared` or `std::optional<>` (that are supposed to perfectly forward for any type) : which initialization form is to be preferred ? It depends on client code.

There is no good answer, they usually go with parenthesis (ideally documenting the choice, so the caller knows what to expect). Idiomatic modern c++11 is to prefer  braced initialization everywhere (it avoids narrowing conversions, avoid c++ most vexing parse, etc..)

---

A potential workaround for disambiguation is to use *named tags*, extensively discussed in this great article from [Andrzej's C++ blog](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/intuitive-interface-part-i/)  :

```
namespace std{
  constexpr struct with_size_t{} with_size{};
  constexpr struct with_value_t{} with_value{};
  constexpr struct with_capacity_t{} with_capacity{};
}

// These contructors do not exist.
std::vector<int> v1(std::with_size, 10, std::with_value, 6);
std::vector<int> v2{std::with_size, 10, std::with_value, 6};
```

This is verbose, and apply only if you can modify the ambiguous type(s) (e.g. types that expose constructors taking an `std::initializer_list` and other constructors whose arguments list maybe converted to an `std::initializer list`)

Comment: So it's the std::vector(size_t count, const T& value) constructor that causes the problem?

Comment: @PhilWright in that example yes, because `{ 42, 2 }` matches both

Answer (score 1):

As with any initialization,

- Use braces when the object contains a value, or several values which are getting piecewise initialized. This includes aggregate classes and numbers.

  Braces appear more like a list of items.
- Use parentheses when the object's initial state is computed from parameters.

  Parentheses appear more like a sequence of function arguments.

This general rule includes the case of a container like `std::vector<int>` which may be initialized with N copies of a number (`std::vector<int>(4,5)`) or a pair of numbers (`std::vector<int>{4,5}`).

By the way, since "uniform" initialization isn't really a catch-all, that term is discouraged. The official name is *brace-initialization*.