# Cannot convert Type in initialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, list-initialization

I think I miss something and I don't know what exactly. Let's take a look at code snippet.

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo { 
    Foo (int n, int p, string s, T t = {})
    : m_n {n}, m_p {p}, m_s {s}, m_t {t}
    {}

    const int m_n;
    const int m_p;
    const string m_s;
    T m_t;
};
```

And usage looks like this:

```
Foo<int> f_int1 {1, 2, "A", 155};
Foo<int> f_int2 {1, 2, "A"};
```

Everything is like intended. But when I want to have a user defined type as a T parameter of Foo, some errors occur. Consider:

```
struct Boo {
    int z;
    int l;
};
```

And usage:

```
Foo<Boo> f_boo1 {1, 2, "A"};
Foo<Boo> f_boo2 {1, 2, "A", {1, 2}};
```

These both instructions give (gcc 4.8.1):

```
cannot convert ‘Boo’ to ‘int’ in initialization
```

I can create Boo objects like this:

```
Boo boo1 {};
Boo boo2 {1, 2};
```

So, could you tell me where the problem is?

Possible solution:

```
struct Boo {
    Boo () : z {}, l {} {}
    Boo (int p1, int p2) : z {p1}, l {p2} {}

    int z;
    int l;
};
```

And both below instructions work as intended:

```
Foo<Boo> f_boo1 {1, 2, "A"};
Foo<Boo> f_boo2 {1, 2, "A", {1, 2}};
```

For me, that's ok, I don't see any reason why not to add two constructors to the class, but what if the type is not mine? Should I write simple wrapper with the constructors?

Thanks,
Artur

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340801/uniform-initialization-fails-to-copy-when-object-has-no-data-members) same reason for the error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you're trying to perform aggregate initialization on `Boo`. See §8.5.4/3:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>
> — If `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1).

You're intending to copy-construct your `Boo`... but really you're doing aggregate initialization, which leads to trying to construct `int z` from a `Boo`, hence the error

> error: no viable conversion from 'Boo' to 'int'

Note that you could reproduce your problem in much less code and without any templates:

```
Boo b;
Boo b2{b}; // error
```

The fix is simple. Just don't use list-initialization:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo { 
    Foo (int n, int p, string s, T t = {})
    : m_n {n}, m_p {p}, m_s {s}, m_t(t)
    //                           ^^^^^^
{};
```

Comment: can you just clarify a bit why `{1,2}` is implicitly converted to a `Boo` instead of being passed to the ctor using aggregate initialization? Isn't `Foo<T>` an aggregate?

Comment: @vsoftco `Boo{1,2}` *does* perform aggregate initialization. `Boo{anything, at, all}` is going to be aggregate initialization because `Boo` is an aggregate.

Comment: @vsoftco `Foo<T>` is *not* an aggregate because it has a user-provided constructor. Full definition (8.5.1): "An aggregate is an array or a class with no user-provided constructors, no private or protected non-static data members, no base classes, and no virtual functions."

Comment: This is a defect in the standard that's been fixed by the resolution of [CWG issue 1467](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467).

Comment: @T.C. Good! Do you know how to track when compilers update for these sorts of things? clang 3.5.0 and gcc 4.9.2 with -std=c++14 both still error (what-used-to-be-correctly?) for this.

Comment: @Barry seems to be fixed on gcc trunk but not clang. I don't know of any good way to track when compilers implement core issue resolutions, though.