# Unneeded conversion happening on std::move

Tags: c++, c++11, stdarray, uniform-initialization

Why is the compiler thinking I am trying to convert from an object of type `Container` to an object of type `MoveTest` in the following code?  Why is the braced constructor being forwarded to the `move_things` variable?  Replacing the `{}` with `()` of course solves the problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

static constexpr int NUMBER{2};

class MoveTest {
public:
  MoveTest(const MoveTest&) {
    cout << "MoveTest(const MoveTest&)" << endl;
  }
  MoveTest(MoveTest&&) {
    cout << "MoveTest(MoveTest&&)" << endl;
  }
  MoveTest() {
    cout << "MoveTest()" << endl;
  }
};

class Container {
public:
  Container() = default;
  Container(Container&&) = default;
  Container(const Container&) = default;
  std::array<MoveTest, NUMBER> move_things;
};

int main() {
  Container container;
  __attribute__((unused)) Container another_one{std::move(container)};

  return 0;
}
```

The error I get is the following

```
Could not convert ‘std::move<Container&>((* & container))’ from ‘std::remove_reference<Container&>::type {aka Container}’ to ‘MoveTest`
```

Does this mean that the uniform initialization syntax is no longer an option for any class with an `std::array`?

The compiler and version I am using is

```
g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
```

Comment: This code compiles fine on G++ 5.3.0. Which compiler do you use?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340801/uniform-initialization-fails-to-copy-when-object-has-no-data-members

Comment: @MattiaF. Just edited my question

Comment: `{}` is aggregate initialization here. It's trying to construct your array of `move_things`